# What is the most future (but still in our universe) setting in gaming?

Tags: video-games

As far as I can recall, the farthest time in the future that a videogame has taken place would be that of Warhammer 40k (41st century).

Has there been a game that takes place in our universe but in a future even further from WH40K?

Comment: Depends on how strict you are with 'our universe' but Off the top of my head, Torment: Tides of Numera takes place a billion years in the future.  I would not be at all surprised if there are video games (or parts of video games) that take place at the very end of the universe's life cyle.

Comment: Are you also including text-based adventures?

Comment: Some world simulators can go millions of years into the future if you want to play them long enough.

Comment: @starpilotsix Basically "our" future. 40K is actually an iffy kind of example, since they don't really delve much into the 21st century and we can't be sure that it's the same as ours.

Comment: @Valorum Absolutely

Comment: @SandroMartinez - I'm debating whether I can be bothered to write a two-line text adventure set 50 trillion years into the future

Answer (score 2):

There's a [video game](http://www.reddwarf.co.uk/news/2016/09/23/play-the-game/) based off of the television series [Red Dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf), which is set three million years in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The game [Gala Collider](https://galacollider.com/?doing_wp_cron=1555953824.9637401103973388671875), a digital card game currently in alpha testing, is set **four billion years** in the future:

> Four billion years in the future, when Earth is a distant memory, devoured eons ago by the same sun that gave it life, the Milky Way is in the middle of a multimillion year collision with its neighboring galaxy, Andromeda